# Ordenar por fecha una union de dos arrays - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
$tickets = Ticket::where('deleted_at', null)->with('client')->get();
foreach($tickets as $ticket){
   $data1[] = [
       'id' => $ticket->id,
       'date' => $ticket->created_at,
       'client' => $ticket->client->name,
       'total' => $ticket->total,
       'type' => 'Ticket'
      ];
   }
$remission = Remission::where('deleted_at', null)->with('client')->get();
foreach($remission as $rem){
   $data2[] = [
        'id' => $rem->id,
        'date' => $rem->created_at,
        'client' => $rem->client->name,
        'total' => $rem->total,
        'type' => 'Remision'
    ];
}
$sales = array_merge($data1, $data2);
```

con esto logro unir ambas colecciones y tengo este resultado

```
|   ID   |           DATE          |   TYPE   | ...
|    1   |   2022/11/26T12:25:08   |  Ticket  | ... 
|    2   |   2022/11/26T12:37:45   |  Ticket  | ... 
|    3   |   2022/11/26T12:38:06   |  Ticket  | ... 
|    1   |   2022/11/26T12:30:21   | Remision | ... 
|    2   |   2022/11/26T12:42:16   | Remision | ...
```

y lo que quiero lograr es este resultado

```
 |   ID   |           DATE          |   TYPE   | ...
 |    1   |   2022/11/26T12:25:08   |  Ticket  | ... 
 |    1   |   2022/11/26T12:30:21   | Remision | ... 
 |    2   |   2022/11/26T12:37:45   |  Ticket  | ... 
 |    3   |   2022/11/26T12:38:06   |  Ticket  | ... 
 |    2   |   2022/11/26T12:42:16   | Remision | ...
```

intente usando `sort` pero no logro dar con el resultado anterior, alguna idea de como lograrlo, gracias

Comment: Desconozco Laravel, pero [en la docu](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#ordering) veo que tiene un método para traer los datos ordenados por uno o varios campos, por ejemplo: `->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')`

Comment: @DjCrazy El problema es que son dos consultas diferentes que luego une con array_merge. Si lo puede hacer todo en una pues vale (que imagino que se puede, tampoco uso laravel) :-)

Comment: @masterguru comprendo tu punto. Tal vez podría usar el método `->union()` para hacer una sola consulta, pero insisto en que desconozco el uso de Laravel y solo son ideas basadas en mi conocimiento básico de `SQL`. Muy válida tu apreciación.

Comment: es correcto, utilice `->orderBy()` pero no me resulto  por como lo explico @masterguru ambas consultas son diferentes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo el ejemplo que aparece en la [documentación de PHP sobre usort() para el ordenamiento de arrays multidimensionales](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php#function.usort.examples.multi), lo puedes hacer de la siguente manera, a continuación de tu código actual:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["date"], $b["date"]);
}

usort($sales, "cmp");
print_r($sales);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! comprendi el funcionamiento del codigo y ya he logrado hacerlo funcionar